# Help with Fitting data to Power regression and the Exponential regression

Tags: r, regression

Im a newbie to the statistic, so appreciate someone's help.

My requirement is to fit the below mentioend data for the Exponential and power regression models.
and my Formulas are

```
Exponential - non linear - y~a*exp(r*x)

SLx <- read_csv(choose.files())
SLx <- data.frame(Day = index(SLx ), SLx , row.names = NULL)
ggplot(Sri_Lanka, aes(x = Day,y = No_of_patients))+ 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method = 'nls', formula = 'y~exp(r*x)', method.args=list (start = list(r=0.1)), se=FALSE)
```

---

```
power -  Non-Linear - y~a*x^b

SLx <- read_csv(choose.files())
SLx <- data.frame(Day = index(SLx ), SLx , row.names = NULL)
ggplot(SLx ,aes(x = Day,y = No_of_patients)) +  geom_point() +  stat_smooth(method = 'nls', formula = 'y~a*x^b', method.args = list(start= c(a = 1,b=1)),se=FALSE)
```

I want to know that, how to fit the data on the line, removing which data ?
My current plot is as below
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use some engineered features to fit your model well with minimal loss. By looking at the data points that you provided **sinusoidal** feature can be a good choice. Look at the below picture sinusoidal wave can fit the dataset with very little loss.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes. Its been really helpful
Thank you